# I don't have force to close the application in android

Tags: java, android, galaxy

i am developing an android application using a new device (**Samsung galaxy core**) the problem is when I try to run the application and I have an error in my code like infinity loop or something like that when the application run in my device a black screen appears and i can't do nothing only restart the device and start over again I don't see the dialog ( force to close application ... ) which I used to have in my old device any help please !

---

thanks for you answers and sorry if i wasn't so clear actually the problem is not in my code it's in the device (i think) for example in this code i haven't declare a new activity in Androidmanifest.xml

```
package com.exadle.df;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newj.class);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

so when the app crash a black screen appears and i can't do nothing ! even as you said "Hold the Home Button for couple of seconds, when the list of running applications shows up, flip your app out." the only thing i can do is Hold power Button to restart the phone

here is the logcat if it can help

```
05-25 15:04:32.281  21017-21017/com.exadle.df D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-25 15:04:32.401  21017-21017/com.exadle.df D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
05-25 15:04:32.401  21017-21017/com.exadle.df D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
05-25 15:04:32.401  21017-21017/com.exadle.df D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
05-25 15:04:32.871  21017-21017/com.exadle.df D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
05-25 15:04:32.881  21017-21017/com.exadle.df D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
05-25 15:04:32.891  21017-21017/com.exadle.df D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
05-25 15:04:32.891  21017-21017/com.exadle.df I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_CL3357771_release_AU (CL3357771)
Build Date: 02/25/13 Mon
Local Branch:
Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
Local Patches: NONE
Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107 +  NOTHING
05-25 15:04:32.941  21017-21017/com.exadle.df D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-25 15:04:37.531  21017-21017/com.exadle.df D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-25 15:04:37.531  21017-21017/com.exadle.df W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b78438)
05-25 15:04:37.541  21017-21017/com.exadle.df E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.exadle.df/com.exadle.df.newj}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1556)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3429)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3600)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3568)
        at com.exadle.df.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i am using Android Studio and i can't use stop execution !

Comment: Try showing the code for your app.

Comment: Hold the Home Button for couple of seconds, when the list of running applications shows up, flip your app out.

Comment: With what environment are you developing? Most iDEs have a pause or stop execution function.

Comment: Interesting. Where's that in Eclipse?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some ideas about what is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code for your app, I can't tell why it is hanging.

If you think it is stuck in an infinite loop, you can use tools to determine roughly where the loop is. A good pace to start is with [the profiling tools in the Android Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html), which will tell you the method where the loop is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

If you show us some of the code or logcat, we may be able to help more. But, I can offer my bit of advice.

When I come across something in my apps that is not working right, or it crashes when it comes to that bit of code, I comment out a few blocks of code at a time, and find the point at which the app runs correctly. So If I had an app that crashed when a specific method was called, I would systematically comment out parts of that method until it stopped crashing. If it only stopped when the entire method was commented out, then I would need to go into the code and try to spot the problem. However, if you comment out half of the method and the remaining code runs, then you know that the problem is in something you commented out. Then you can narrow that down to the exact problem.

Just make sure you comment out blocks of code that make sense. Don't just comment out a bracket, and then have your program give you errors. Comment out the code intelligently.

Since your entire app isn't working, make sure that your preliminary activity is set correctly in your Manifest. If it is your splash, make sure that it is called when the app starts. There is a setting/line of code in the manifest somewhere, but I forget where it is. If all of that is correct, then start commenting out the code in that activity systematically. Start with the last method called, then the second to last, and so on. When it starts running, look at the code you have commented out and try to find the problem.

This is all we can do without any code or logcat. If the problem turns out not to be in the code, but in the phone, then this would be better suited on the Android Enthusiasts forum. You could ask for a migration if this is the case. Hope this helps!

UPDATE

---

I am still not 100% sure what the problem is, but I can suggest some changes in your code that may or may not work.

1. Make sure your `newj` activity is in your Manifest.XML. There should be a line of code that says:

   `<activity android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="newj"></activity>`

If that doesn't help at all, you can try these also.

2. Instead of having your intent outside the click listener, put in inside. I find that having not in the same OnClickListener or if statement or method can cause a problem to two. So your code would be:

   `btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newj.class);
       startActivity(intent); //and get rid of MainActivity.this.
   }
   });`
3. If that doesn't work, then this method is more in-depth, but I think it is safer.

First, you want to go into the XML for your button, and add these two lines.

```
android:Clickable="true"
android:onClick="methodToBeCalled"
```

These two lines take the place of the OnClickListener, and make the button clickable and tell the program which method to call when the button is clicked. So you need to make a new method, outside of onCreate, that looks like this.

```
public static void methodToBeCalled(View view){

        final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newj.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

So basically what happens is that the code in the XML makes the button clickable, and says to call the method, "methodToBeCalled" when it is clicked. Then it looks for that method in your mainActivity class (because that XML file is linked to this activity) and it runs that activity, starting the Intent `intent` which starts the Activity `newj`. Confusing, right? Not really. The XML tells the program to run the method "methodToBeCalled", which starts newj.

Try these methods in order. If method 1 doesn't work, move onto 2. Then 3. If none of these work, update your question with the new logcat, your entire `MainActivity` code, your entire `activity_main` XML code, and your entire `AndroidManifest.XML` code. We can move on from there.

If this does turn out to be a problem with your phone and not the code, flag for migration to [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/). You will get better help there if this does turn out to be a problem with the phone itself, and not the code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: well thanks a lot for your help and about what you say actually I know what's wrong with the code I haven't declare a new activity in Manifest.XML as you said in the first method and i just do that to show my real problem (my device freeze if there is a problem in my code) anyway thanks and i will try in  Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange